# Check traffic rules in openshift

Tags: containers, openshift, istio, iptables, traffic

We've got an OpenShift cluster with Istio in which we want to debug routing rules. But in my container I don't even have iptables utility or iptables config file with rule chains. How can I check traffic rules from within container?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using istio, I assume most of the traffic goes through `istio-proxy` container. You can exec into `istio-proxy` container with

```text
kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -c istio-proxy -- bash
```

and check iptables there.

---

Optionally you can install [Kiali](https://kiali.io/) with

```text
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.12/samples/addons/kiali.yaml
```

and then open it with

```text
istioctl dashboard kiali
```

This will give you an insight into your Istio mesh, and routing of each of the workloads.

Comment: Thank you, this answer makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check your istio configs like virtualServices then if you want to go deeper you can  use `istioctl proxy-config routes <pod-name>`.